# Java - Interface does not allow ArrayList to function correctly

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

I'm trying to implement an interface named board `Board` but whenever I try to add anything to the ArrayList I've created in it it throws

`- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on token "Tile1", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this 
     token`

This is the full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public interface BoardTest {
    public ArrayList<Land> lands = new ArrayList<Land>();

    Land Tile1 = new Land(0,1,0,0,0, "Tile 1");
    lands.add(Tile1);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? You can't have floating code like this, even in classes.

Comment: do you know what an interface is?

Comment: Read up on the interface basics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: I think you're not showing us all the code here. Show the interface you want to implement, then show the class implementing the interface. From what you have shown it's not clear what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

Interfaces can't have implementation.

You can't create an ArrayList or call any of its methods in an interface.  All you can do it create a method signature for a method that might or might not do it the way you've written.

The whole idea of a interface is to separate "what" from "how".

Maybe you meant this:

```
public interface Board {
    void land(Land l);
}

public class BoardImpl implements Board {
   List<Land> squares = new ArrayList<Land>();

   public void land(Land l) {
      this.squares.add(l);
   }
}
```

Comment: the moron who downvoted you needs help. better change your wording so even *he* can understand it :(

Comment: Thank you, Bohemian.  Reason seems to have prevailed.

Comment: not really - you still have a downvote :(

Comment: Ooh, you're right.  Can't perform a lobotomy on every deserving person here.  Too bad.

Answer (score 2):

An `Interface` contains just `method` declarations and fields declaration with initialization.
You cannot have statements like method call, in an interface.

You should probably use a class, that implements the interface and do all those stuffs in there. And just have method declaration in your interface.